# Changing variable dynamically via user input in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I want to produce an endless loop that would to different things depending on some user input.
When the .py is executed the loop starts and does some 'main' programm and the input window opens for the user. When typing 'alt1' the loop jumps in to the function 'main_alt1' and so on.

```
user_input = 'main'
user_input = input()

while True:
    if user_input == 'main'
        main()
    elif user_input == 'alt1'
        main_alt1()
    elif user_input == 'exit'
        exit()
```

The problem here is that the input is either given once before the loop (like in the example) or it stops the loop when the input is inside the loop until the input is given.
Does anyone has a smart way to do something like that. It doesn't need to be with input().

Comment: It makes sense for the `input()` to be inside the loop, before the `if` statement. Otherwise the same function will be called in an infinite loop, which I doubt you want.

Comment: No, I want the `main()` to be called in an infinite loop since it needs to check something every few seconds.

Comment: `main()` won't be called in an infinite loop if the user had entered `alt1`. Instead `main_alt1()` would be called infinitely.

Comment: But the loop pauses while it's waiting for the user input.

Comment: OK then, you are going to need multiple threads. One thread is an input loop which will set the `user_input` variable. The other is the main loop which reads the value of `user_input`, as it currently does. Check out the [threading](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/threading.html#module-threading) module. It might be possible using [`async`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/asyncio.html#module-asyncio), but I'm not too familiar with it yet.

Comment: There was a similar question I gave answer to recently [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65595027/). If you look at the 2nd example, it demonstrates something pretty close to what you need, using multi-threading and listening on events in your main function.

Comment: Thank you! The 2nd example is doing exactly what I was searching for.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to use a class to process the user input:
(I updated the code with the process method)

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep


class InvalidAction(Exception):
    pass


class Cmd:

    def __init__(self):
        self._active_thread = None

    def _action_hi(self):
        while True:
            print('Hi!')
            sleep(1)

    def _action_ping(self):
        while True:
            print('Pong!')
            sleep(1)

    @staticmethod
    def _get_method_name(action):
        return f'_action_{action}'

    def process(self, action: str):
        method_name = self._get_method_name(action)
        if not hasattr(self, method_name):
            raise InvalidAction

        if self._active_thread is not None:
            self._active_thread.terminate()

        self._active_thread = Process(target = getattr(self, method_name, None))
        self._active_thread.start()


def main():
    cmd = Cmd()

    while True:
        try:
            user_input = input('Action: ')
            cmd.process(user_input)

        except InvalidAction as e:
            print(f'Invalid Action!')

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('Exiting the loop.')
            break

        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Something went wrong - {e}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Can I insert a message that gets printed every second while I am not entering anything via input? Let's say `print('Waiting for input')`?

Comment: No, the input method works in this way , it waits for the user input

Comment: Ok so that's exactly my problem. I don't want to wait for the user input. But when the user enters something I want to change something in the infinit loop.

Comment: You can run a thread in any action method and with the new action, stop the previous one and start the new thread.

Comment: I added the sample code with the process method.

Answer (score 0):

```
user_input = 'main'
user_input = input()

while True:
    if user_input == 'main'
        main()
    elif user_input == 'alt1'
        main_alt1()
    elif user_input == 'exit'
        exit()
    user_input = input()
```

Taking the the input again at the end of loop works. Since it is `while True` it runs infinitely till user enters exit

Comment: This pauses the while loop until the user enter his input again. So the `main()` is only called once until the user gives input at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

after calling every function you can again take update from user to change variable

```
import keyboard 

while True:
    if keyboard.read_key() == 'a':
        main_alt1()
    elif keyboard.read_key() == 'b':
        main_alt2()
    elif keyboard.read_key() == 'e':
        exit()
    else:
        main()
```

Comment: This pauses the loop until the input is entered after `main()`. I want `main()` to be called in an infinite loop until I give input to do different.

Comment: try this updated code with keyboard interruption