# How to interrupt ocaml program on user input

Tags: multithreading, ocaml

I have a program that can indefinitely look for an optimal solution to my problem. I let the user decide the time it can run to find a solution and once this time is spent, the program stop, create some log files, print some debug data and show the best solution found.

Now, I'd like to allow the user to stop the program earlier by prompting some message in the terminal if he doesn't want to wait until the end.

I found how to do it in python thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65595027/how-to-interrupt-python-program-on-user-input), and was thinking if it would be possible to have the same architecture in OCaml.

Ideally, I would have 2 threads :

```ml
(* ___ Main thread ___ *)
start_program_thread();
Printf.printf "prompt `kill` to stop the program%!";
let rec aux() = match input_line() with 
  | "kill" -> (* user_didnt_stop set to false *)
  | _ -> aux()
in aux()


(* __________________________ *)


(* ___ Program thread ___ *)
while user_didnt_stop && Sys.time() -. start_time < max_time do
 (* search for optimal solution *)
done;
create_log_files();
send_debug_datas();
show_best_solution()
```

Can this be achieved with [the Thread lib](https://ocaml.org/api/Thread.html) ?

Would it be possible to allow the `program thread` to print things without breaking the main program ?

I'm working with `OCaml 4.12.0` with the [diskuv-ocaml windows install](https://diskuv.gitlab.io/diskuv-ocaml/)

Comment: It could depend upon your version of Ocaml, and of your operating system. Consider some [continuation-passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) approach

Comment: I'm not sure to understand how continuation-passing style could help me

Comment: I don't understand your question neither. It certainly depends upon your operating system. Are you allowed to use [Debian](http://debian.org/) ?

Comment: I'd like to stay on windows if possible. My question is about the possibility or not to make a sort of clean SIGINT in ocaml. The user would be able to send a message in the terminal which would change the state of a boolean making the search_for_solution thread stop

Comment: Maybe you could take inspiration from the source code of [Ocaml](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/archive/4.13.1.tar.gz)

Comment: My suggestion is to use Lwt, not only it will enable you to solve your problem, it gives you a much nicer and richer IO interface, and is very portable. You can run it no only on Unixes and Windows, but on JS backends as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `input_line` function blocks in the operating system so in order to unblock it, you have to use the corresponding facilities of your operating system or, alternatively, stick to the non-blocking IO. You can definitely use the Unix module to implement that but it is hard and tedious to do this in a potable way. The good news is that someone already did it. There are plenty of solutions in OCaml, starting from using non-blocking asynchronous-style IO, like Lwt or Async, or using specialized readline-like libraries.